# Do we have S3 API and a CLI command to delete Object storage account in Softlayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have around 75 S3 Object storage accounts on Softlayer and I want to delete them using SL API or CLI. I'm aware of deleting them via Dashboard one after another but I want an API and a CLI command to add it in a script to delete.

## slcli object-storage

Usage: slcli object-storage [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Object Storage.

Options:
  -h, --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  accounts   List object storage accounts.
  endpoints  List object storage endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

there is not a slcli client for object storage the most nearly is the swift client, as softlayer object storage is based on OpenStack you can you the swift client take a look at this links:

https://www.swiftstack.com/docs/integration/python-swiftclient.html
https://docs.openstack.org/developer/python-swiftclient/swiftclient.html
http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/radosgw/swift/python/

in this page you can see how to configure the swift client for your softlayer's account (it is at the botton of the page)

https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/waelriac/managing-softlayer-object-storage-through-rest-apis

In regards the API here some links:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/objectstorageapi
https://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/

Also Softlayer has some object storage clients that may interest you, you can find them here:

https://github.com/softlayer

maybe this one may interest you:
https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-object-storage-python

For S3 this is the documentation of the API
https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/

there is not a client for S3 from softlayer, but you could use the AMazon s3 client http://s3tools.org/s3cmd it should works using the configuration for your S3 objects in softlayer

Basically to cancel any softlayer's product you need to cancel the associated billing item take a look at this documentation:

[Getting started with REST and the SoftLayer Billing API](http://sldn.softlayer.com/node/274103)

Regards

Comment: For S3, the API documentation doesn't list anywhere how to delete an Object storage account.

Comment: well there is not any cli comand to delete the account, I updated my answer adding how to cancel it, basically you need to cancel the associated billing item.

Comment: one tier of SL object storage uses Swift API like you mention, but they also offer S3 api access to another tier